# swift subset of array match the duplicate elements

Tags: arrays, swift, set

Scene:

```
let superTrue = [1,2,3,3]
let superFalse = [1,2,3]

let sub = [2,3,3]
```

Requirements:

`sub` is subset of `superTrue` but not `superFalse`.

The wrong code:

```
print(Set(sub).isSubset(of: superTrue)) // true
print(Set(sub).isSubset(of: superFalse)) // true
```

because `Set(sub)` is `[2,3]`, removes the duplicated `3`

Don't remove the duplicate, and compute subset, any ideas?

Comment: Does the order matter? In other words, if `sub = [3,2,3]` would it still match with `superTrue`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Set` will always remove duplicates by its nature.

One of the options would be to count occurrences of all elements in all three arrays:

```swift
let subCounts = sub.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1, default: 0] += 1 }
let superTrueCounts = superTrue.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1, default: 0] += 1 }
let superFalseCounts = superFalse.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1, default: 0] += 1 }
```

And then to check if values for all keys of the wannabe subarray equals or are less than the values of the same keys of the "super" array:

```swift
subCounts
  .keys
  .allSatisfy { subCounts[$0, default: 0] <= superTrueCounts[$0, default: 0] }
subCounts
  .keys
  .allSatisfy { subCounts[$0, default: 0] <= superFalseCounts[$0, default: 0] }
```

This will gives the output you expect (as far as I understood the questions).

**Note 1.** Since you originally tried to use `Set`, I assumed the order doesn't matter and you only care about specific elements and the number of their occurrences.

**Note 2.** The elements should be `Equatable`.